# R plspm working with categorical and numeric variables

Tags: r, path, numeric, categorical-data

I am working with the package plspm in R and I'm trying to build a Partial Least  Squares Path Model with it. I'm having weird results when running the analysis with the categorical variables, because they don't fit in the blocks (but numeric variables work ok).

I wanted to ask if it is possible to work with both numeric and categorical variables, or if I have to remove one type.

Would be great if someone could lend me a hand on this. Thanks!